# Is it possible to use webRTC cross-browser?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am using webRTC and doing peer connection using a self implementation of SIP with websockets.

When I test the flow I am able to stream and see both remote and local streams on each peers. This test is on the same browser different tabs for each peer. Test done in Firefox and Chrome successfully

When I do the test one peer in Firefox and another peer in Chrome, or vice versa, then I cannot see local stream but I can with remote.

No exceptions or errors are shown in the console.
In which cases the stream fails when using one peer and other peer in different browsers but doing all in the same browser it works?

What can I do to debug this?

Comment: Start by making use of adapter.js - this thing is practically mandatory use for WebRTC these days (https://github.com/webrtc/adapter). Also why not use SIP.js? What's wrong with it?

Comment: are you testing on a machine with only a single webcam? Then Chrome can not access the webcam while Firefox is using it.

The easiest options are to either attach another webcam or change Firefox to use a fake device by creating a new preference media.navigator.streams.fake set to true in about:config

Comment: @PhilippHancke thanks for this information, you help me a lot.

Comment: @PhilippHancke i disagree with your point. Did you try apprtc one in Chrome and Firefox? Both browsers have evolved a lot. It is possible to Share a single Webcam to both chrome and firefox. But Media APIs might be different.

Comment: You're doing something wrong, and we need to see your code to help.

Answer (score 0):

I bet there is a SDP compatibility issues between browsers when you try it as SIP over websocket in your implementation. You have to try open source libs like SIPjs, JSsip, SIPml5 which is already doing SIP over websocket.

> No exceptions or errors are shown in the console.

Make sure you have added logging to all the possible failure cases `catch(err)` while accessing webRTC API's.

Online demo of JSsip https://tryit.jssip.net/

Comment: My webscoket server only passes SDP (generated on each browser) from one peer to another. It only relays this information without modifying it. Both SDP are then passed into the constructor of the peerconnection instance with no errors even with catch.

Comment: @DidacHerrera Try https://apprtc.appspot.com/params.html in audio only mode with FireFox and Chrome to see audio works

Comment: Debuggin I found that when the callee (so the caller on the other browser already has the stream actived and shown on video element) is about to got the local media, the object is created but with attribute active = false. That is why peer connection is created succesfully without errors but I cannot see callee stream... This attribute is read only so I cannot force it. Who could it be? Why when a stream is active in the one peer the other peer creates an inactive mediastream object?

Comment: Additional information is that I am testing it inside an ubuntu virtualbox and a windows host

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC is available in both Chrome and Firefox, but the some of the APIs are different.
You would need to write an adapter or use an existing WebRTC adapter library for compatibility between those two.

For example, a simple adapter would look something like this:

```
var MediaStream =  $window.webkitMediaStream || $window.MediaStream;
var PeerConnection = $window.mozRTCPeerConnection || $window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || $window.RTCPeerConnection;
var IceCandidate = $window.mozRTCIceCandidate || $window.webkitRTCIceCandidate || $window.RTCIceCandidate;
var SessionDescription = $window.mozRTCSessionDescription || $window.webkitRTCSessionDescription || $window.RTCSessionDescription;
```

I would strongly recommend using an adapter library like https://github.com/webrtc/adapter so you don't have to manually handle all the edge cases.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that `msRTCPeerConnection` and `msRTCSessionDescription` are not a thing. Never were. I also doubt `webkitRTCSessionDescription` ever existed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @jib, my custom adapter was quite old. I'm using the WebRTC adapter from https://github.com/webrtc/adapter at the moment.

Comment: @jib I am using adapter.js in order to do so. My javascript, the same script, works well both on Firefox and Chrome, without modifying it. The problem comes when one peer is in chrome and the other peer is in Firefox, the remote stream is not shown despite it is being received. The onaddstream is fired when remote stream comes but it's not showed on the html video element when assigned to it. I tried to debug but no error is shown. I am using adapter, this works well when both peers are in the same browser but not when on peer (caller o callee) is in different browser than the other peer.

Comment: @DidacHerrera Again, hard to comment without seeing your code. Timing and the order of doing things tend to matter when answering a call, e.g. always set `setRemoteDescription` on an offer immediately, and make sure you have gUM before answering. Basic WebRTC between Firefox and Chrome generally works fine. E.g. [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vv2vxtt/) wfm when I cut'n'paste offer and answer between Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @jibI found that when the callee (so the caller on the other browser already has the stream actived and shown on video element) is about to got the local media, the object is created but with the attribute active = false. That is why peer connection is created succesfully without errors but I cannot see callee stream... This attribute is read only so I cannot force it. Who could it be? Why when a stream is active in the one peer the other peer creates an inactive mediastream object?

Comment: Additional information is that I am testing it inside an ubuntu virtualbox and a windows host